# how to determine specific item to be selected in combobox with javascript

Tags: javascript, select, combobox

when I open the combobox via contextMenu, always the same item is selected.
How can I determine that one of the other items is selected?
For instance, there are 3 items "car1", "car2", "car3" and when I open the combobox "car1" appears in the list first. So how would I get e.g. "car2" appears in the list first?
Thanks very much!

Comment: with HTML code or with Javascript code ?

Comment: there is no combobox in HTML...

Comment: With JavaScript do I mean

Answer (score 0):

if you mean a select element, you can change the order of items

```
<select id="list">
  <option value="2">Car 2</option>
  <option value="1">Car 1</option>
  <option value="3">Car 3</option>
</select>
```

you could also set the default item with the selected attribute:

```
<select id="list">
  <option value="1">Car 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Car 2</option>
  <option value="3">Car 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there still another way to do it?

Comment: you can use js to set the selected element which someone already answered

Answer (score 0):

in JS you simply have to set  the value of your select

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

// set the select on the second cat
myForm.miaou.value = 'c2'
```

```html
<form action="xxx" name="my-form">

 
  <!-- other form elements -->

  <select name="miaou">
    <option value="c1">Cat 1</option>
    <option value="c2">Cat 2</option>
    <option value="c3">Cat 3</option>
  </select>

</form>
```